# Datagrid showing 1 result only

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have created a code to display data from datagrid and I have 3 data on the database but the query only display 1 result. here is my code below:

```vb
 Public Sub displayGrid()
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)
        SQL = "Select * from IPQC_modelParameter"
        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection)
            Dim ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            For x As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0) 'this will add a new record on top, always
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("id")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("full_model")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("model_name")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("parameter")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("instrument")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(5).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("nominal")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(6).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("tolerance")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("ucl")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(8).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("lcl")
                'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(9).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("uot")
                'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(10).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("lot")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(11).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("mrnominal")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(12).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("mrucl")
                'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(13).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("status")
                'DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(14).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("mp_id")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(15).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("usl")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(16).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("lsl")
                DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(17).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(x)("conversion")

            Next

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't populate a `DataGridView` like that. You should simply assign the `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property of the grid and you're done.  That will even create the columns automatically if you like but, if you want to add the columns yourself, just set their `DataPropertyName` to specify which source column to bind to.  Also, don't create a `DataSet` if all you want is a `DataTable`.  Just create a `DataTable`.

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` the rest is cruft

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, i know the datasource that you teached to me. I'm going to retrieve the data on datagrid by using cellchanged an put it to textboxes, that's why im using the dataset. or is it still okay to use the datatable and be able to do exactly what i want?

Comment: my bad, cellcontent click

Comment: You're already using a `DataTable`.  What do you think `ds.Tables(0)` is?  There's no point creating a `DataSet` if you're only going to use a `DataTable`.  Just create a `DataTable` and use it.

Comment: Also, there's no need to handle any event.  Just bind the `TextBoxes` to the same data source as the grid and then selecting a grid row will populate the `TextBoxes` without any code.